# Openjdk 20 does not support java generics？

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I declare a variable *data*,type is generic *T*.But the compiler reported an error:Cannot resolve symbol 'T'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRTrT.png)

My project
My java version is OpenJDK 20, is it change the way to use generics?
If i use the another version, java1.8, and change the Projectsettings,Settings, it works.
Does anyone know the syntax for Openjdk20 version about the generics?
Here is some Maven pom.xml

```
<name>Server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>3.1.2</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Does anyone know the syntax for Openjdk20 version about the generics?

Comment: generics do work, but you'll need for your class/instance declare what type T is

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank u guys! My problems is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing magical about the name "T", and using it by itself won't make a member of a generic type. You need to provide the type argument in the class' declaration:

```java
public class Result<T> {
    // Here -------^

    // other members, snipped for brevity's sake

    public T data;
}
```

Comment: It does work, im a java fresher. Thank you for your answer sincerely!